# Find the numbers in sequence (Created by PC App)

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

***Hi all.*** 
This image is a series of number in sequence created by computer app.

[image: Numbers in Sequence] 
You can see there are five numbers in above row and five numbers in row below. 

***1) Pls find what will be the numbers for A-B-C-D-E and F-G*** 

 ***2) What is the number to put inside the green box?***

***Facts of the image*** 
The sequence comes from horizontal yellow line and vertical yellow line is the same number (which will appeared in the green box).

Hint 1:

> I made this by famous computer application. Not by myself :P

Hint 2: **Dare to look some answers!?**

> C is 12.

Hint 3: **Dare to look some answers!?**

> E is 48.

Hint 4:

> The number in green box "?" is comes from F-G sequence, A-B-C-D-E sequence.

Comment: "created by PC App"? That means nothing. Did you calculate the sequences using software like Mathematica? Surely your computer didn't just spew out random numbers from zero input. Why is it so important?

Comment: "Why is it so important?" : I don't think I said it is important, but telling the truth, that "the answer is created by PC App". 
I just want to let the readers know I wasn't find out the answer by myself.

Answer (score 5):

As-is, there are infinitely many "logics" that lead to a "solution".

The top row are [even numbers $n$ so that $6 \nmid \frac n2 \cdot \sigma \left( \frac n2 \right)$](https://oeis.org/A239993). The next one is $F=32$.

The middle row are [highly composite numbers $+1$ starting at 5](https://oeis.org/A135372). The next one is $G=49$.

The row $A,B,C,D,E,?$ is calculated as $2 \cdot \text{middle row} - \text{top row}$. The answers are $A=8$, $B=6$, $C=12$, $D=32$, $E=48$, $?=66$.

Comment: Nice try for answers! But as I said, according to the PC software F, G and ? are not right. F is actually 31. G is 42 and ? is 53. => where A,B,C,D,E produce the number 53 there.
Thank you for the answer and you logic to solution. It's impressive to me.